# Can a tilted plane's coordinate system be changed?

Tags: three.js, coordinate-systems

I add a new THREE.PlaneGeometry() to my scene and it appears at [0,0,0] upright in the XY plane with its normal facing along the +Z axis.  I then issue plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2 to lay the plane down so that its normal is now facing UP.

The problem I am experiencing is that now the plane's +Y axis is directed along the global -Z axis.

Since the plane is representing terrain, I want to be able to adjust the height of vertices to simulate height above sea level (altitude).  Thus what I **want** to be able to write in code is something like this:

```
plane.geometry.vertices[i].y = 3;
```

...but what that does is simply move the vertex -3 units along the Z axis leaving the plane as flat as a tack.

I *can* write an abstraction function to map the coordinates for me, but I would prefer not to do that as it adds code and hinders direct access to the data structure (which is nice whilst experimenting).

Is there some way of *permanently* changing the plane's coordinate system so that it matches the global coordinate system?  Such that plane.geometry.vertices[i].y++ would, in fact, result in a bump in the terrain?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rotating the mesh, apply a rotation to the geometry itself before you create the mesh.

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );
```

three.js r.58